# Two file Comparison with while .sh

Tags: linux, file, scripting, comparison, multiple-columns

The script written in `sh` is used to compare the columns of two different files and give the output.

**File 1 content**

```
9999
0
2
3
```

**File 2 content**

```
SDC 4
abc 0
abx 2
cdf 3
```

**Script logic**

```
 while read Colm_1_File1 <&3 && Colm_1_File2 Colm_2_File2 <&4

     do

     Check_Count_File1=$Colm_1_File1

     v_File_Name=$Colm_1_File2

     Check_Count_File2=$Colm_1_File2

     if [ "$Check_Count_File1" -eq "$Check_Count_File2" ]

      then

      echo "$v_File_Name:- OK" 
      elif [ "$Colm_1_File1" -eq "9999" ]

      then

      echo "$v_File_Name File Missing"

      else

      echo "$v_File_Name:- NOK" 

     fi

     done 3<File1 4<File2
```

The `if` condition only works from "0"; any other number that is equal doesn't match. `elif` and `else` behave as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is what you need, your variable name `Colm_1_File2` is written two times, hence the issue

```
while read Colm_1_File1 <&3 && read Colm_1_File2 Colm_2_File2 <&4
 do
 Check_Count_File1=$Colm_1_File1
 v_File_Name=$Colm_1_File2
 Check_Count_File2=$Colm_2_File2
 if [ "$Check_Count_File1" -eq "$Check_Count_File2" ]
  then
  echo "$v_File_Name:- OK"
  elif [ "$Colm_1_File1" -eq "9999" ]
  then
  echo "$v_File_Name File Missing"
  else
  echo "$v_File_Name:- NOK"
 fi
 done 3<File1 4<File2
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: when I use Colm_1_File1 ,Colm_1_File2, Colm_2_File2 directly for comparison the issue is not replicated , however when I initialize them in a variable the issue comes up

Comment: Correct this as well `Check_Count_File2=$Colm_1_File2` to `Check_Count_File2=$Colm_2_File2`